# Wrap CSV lat/long points around 180 meridian in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, csv, proj

I have a CSV file with lat/long coordinates. I also have a custom CRS to center the map on the Indian Ocean. Is there a way for me to force the points to plot on the blank band of the map where the 180 meridian is?

My proj4 string is `+proj=eqc +lon_0=90 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +lon_wrap=90`. `+lon_wrap=90` doesn't appear to have done anything.

[image: Blank band around 180 when centered on Indian Ocean]

---

As a temporary solution, I first converted my CSV points to a points shapefile, then rasterized my shapefile at the appropriate resolution. In my case my CSV file contained lat/long coordinates every 1/2 degree, so I set my resolution to be 0.5 map units = 1 pixel, because my projection was in degrees lat/long. My raster wraps with no issues:

[image: fixed raster map]

However, as another user noted, this is only a visual solution and doesn't actually solve my original problem.

Comment: @iant The question you marked this as a duplicate of was not helpful for me, nor is it a duplicate of my current question, as it applies to vector polygons and not points. You cannot split points in half.

Comment: Did you try using the projection in the question

Comment: Yes, unfortunately simply changing the proj4 parameters isn't an easy fix. They are simply points that are in lat/long so I'm not sure why there's an empty band while the rest of it projects correctly.